# How to do page reveal animations with IronRouter?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using meteor & IronRouter, and trying to do some javascript-driven animations when the template is ready/rendered.

However, the IR hook events don't seem to fire when they should.

onBeforeAction and onAfterAction only seem to fire before the new page is rendered.
So there is no updated DOM to animate.

I also tried overriding the action, calling render myself, and then animating.
however, the DOM is still not updated... even using `Meteor.defer`

```
    action: ->          
        this.render()  # works ok
        Meteor.defer ->
            Template.SceneView.animateScene()
```

This was still getting called while the old template was present. I guess since Meteor is still updating async-ly, and so defer() didn't really defer...

So a hack around this is to call the animate function from the template itself, and then also use `Meteor.defer` to call the animation, so the DOM is updated.

The [Blaze rendered() hook](http://meteor.github.io/blaze/docs.html#template_rendered) only fires once on template creation.

Separately there are some new ui_hooks in Blaze, but these seem to be before insert or deletes happen. I guess I could use this and take over the whole DOM manipulation but that seems like overkill for just playing some animations when a page is ready...
https://github.com/percolatestudio/transition-helper/blob/master/transition-helper.js

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE. I found out [about the afterFlush event](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_afterflush)

So it seems that having reactive templates, somehow makes defer timing not work.
Instead if I use the following, the DOM is all updated in time for the animation trigger.

```
    action: ->          
        this.render()
        Deps.afterFlush ->
            Template.SceneView.animateScene()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use plain css, if you have a package like animate.css in your app (http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

If you have this class `animated bounceIn` on the div or element thats at the top of your template it will also display an animation when the template comes into view.

Comment: I've found CSS animations to be pretty unreliable with meteor. I think its because meteor is doing something like recycling DOM elements, or something tricky. the animations don't fire when you come back to a page. I am using velocityJS tho. Also I've found that CSS keyframe animations run very slowly on mobile devices.

Comment: @dcsan Has this been your experience with Meteor 0.8.0 forward or with previous versions?

Comment: this is with the latest release. I think when Blaze removes fragments they are not destroyed, just kept around to be re-inserted if you go back to that route and no Deps have changed. ie caching page fragments. This is probably good for performance but breaks CSS animations when you go back to previous pages. There are some brutal hack workarounds but I found CSS keyframes bad performance anyway, so shifted to JS animations with VelocityJS